# Angular ng-repeat assíncrono

Tags: angularjs, api, angular, async, ng-repeat

Estou usando o Angular 1.6.10 para mostrar os dados de uma API, como a busca dos dados é assíncrona, acredito que o ng-repeat é executado antes dos dados serem carregados:

```js
angular
  .module('appDataPOA', [])
  .controller('controllerDataPOA', async function() {
    this.data = await getDataPOA();
    console.log(this.data); //Retorna o array de objetos corretamente
  });

async function getDataPOA() {
  if (navigator.onLine) {
    let json = [];

    for (let resource of ['c003f659-dc05-4e64-8a5a-0f730ac8cff2', 'c2da9ff7-94c8-43af-8141-d03f8d325739', '9b019d7c-1956-4cf8-bc75-9041284d5d81']) {
      json = json.concat(
        await fetch(`http://datapoa.com.br/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=${resource}&limit=500`)
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(dataJSON => dataJSON.result.records)
        .catch(error => error)
      );
    }

    localStorage.dataPOA = JSON.stringify(json);

    return json;
  } else if (localStorage.dataPOA) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.dataPOA);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-BR" ng-app="appDataPOA">

<body ng-controller="controllerDataPOA as control">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>

  <h1>{{control.data.length}} universidades, faculdades, escolas estaduais e federais cadastradas</h1>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in control.data">
        <td>{{row.NOME}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

`getDataPOA` é uma função que pega os dados da API (na verdade de 3 e junta tudo)

Comment: `acredito que o ng-repeat é executado antes dos dados serem carregados` Isso é incorreto. o ng-repeat é executado durante todo o tempo de vida da página. Uma pergunta, depois das requisições nas APIs, você fez um `console.log()` pra se certificar que os dados realmente foram capturados? Pode ser que eles não foram capturados, assim não tem nada para mostrar.

Comment: Fiz está no código que postei, então qual é o problema?

Comment: Você fez um `console.log()` apenas após a chamada da função, eu pensei em colocar eles em cada `then` do seu código, para ter certeza que está tudo correto.

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor? Nao entendi o por quê, o que vai adiantar?

Comment: Usando um console.log você pode ter uma ideia do que diabos está se passando na sequência de instruções que você tá passando pro javascript. Vamos dizer que pelo seu código devia estar funcionando, mas durante as requisições ele recebe um objeto nulo de resposta e ai a coisa começa a dar errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Angular possui sua própria implementação para consumo de APIs, o [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

```
angular.module('httpExample', [])
.controller('FetchController', ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache',
  function($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
    $scope.method = 'GET';
    $scope.url = 'example.com';

    $scope.fetch = function() {
      $scope.code = null;
      $scope.response = null;

      $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url, cache: $templateCache}).
        then(function(response) {
          $scope.status = response.status;
          $scope.data = response.data;
        }, function(response) {
          $scope.data = response.data || 'Request failed';
          $scope.status = response.status;
      });
    };
  }
]);
```